# Проблема в реализации программы угадывающей число

Tags: java

Программа должна считать количество попыток, которое потребовалось пользователю, чтобы угадать число. И в конце сообщать, сколько было попыток, также должна подсказывать пользователю, что он ошибся в знаке, если программа загадала положительное число, а пользователь ввёл отрицательное. И наоборот.

Программа должна загадывать целое число из отрезка от [−10;10], исключая ноль. При этом, постараться, чтобы распределение случайных чисел генерируемых программой было равномерных (т. е. в случае выпадения нуля его нельзя просто заменить на какое-то другое подходящее число, например, на 1, ведь тогда 1 буде выпадать с вдвое большей вероятностью, чем остальные числа).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double prog, user;
        prog = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 10) + 10);
        System.out.println("Я загадала число от -10 до 10, отгадайте его.");
        do {
            System.out.print("Вводите ваше число: ");

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            user = input.nextDouble();
            if(user == prog) {
                System.out.println("Вы угадали!");
            } else {

                if ( user == Math.floor(user) && user > -10 && user < 10) {
                    System.out.print("Вы не угадали! ");

                    if( prog < user ) {
                        System.out.println("Моё число меньше.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Моё число больше.");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Вы ввели не подходящее число!");
                }
            }
        } while( user != prog );
        System.out.println("До свиданья!");
    }
}
```

Подскажите что не правильно в цикле который подсчитает количество попыток и выводит их результат на экран в веденных пользователем,не могу понять что не правильно?

Выводит не тот результат который нужно.

Вот переделал не много результат программы

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double prog, user;

        prog = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 - 10);
        System.out.println("Я загадала число от -10 до 10, отгадайте его.");


        do {

            System.out.print("Вводите ваше число: ");

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            user = input.nextDouble();

           {
               for(int count = 0;count < user;count++){

               if(user == prog) {
                System.out.println("Вы угадали!");
            } else {

                if ( user == Math.floor(user) && user > -10 && user < 10) {
                    System.out.print("Вы не угадали! ");

                    if( prog < user ) {
                        System.out.println("Моё число меньше.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Моё число больше.");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Вы ввели не подходящее число!");
                 }
               }

              System.out.println("Количество попыток " + count);  }
           }
        } while( user != prog );
         System.out.println("До свиданья!");

        }
}
```

цикл

```
for(int count = 0;count < user;count++)
```

Как можно его исправить?

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Comment: Для того, чтобы не заменять 0 на заведомо известное число, сделать надо загадывание отдельной функцией.

 function getRandomInt(){
  prog = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) - 10;
  return prog;
 }

Загадываем целое число от 0 до 20 включительно. И проверять при возврате, если prog=0, то загадывать заново. Тогда шансы будут равны у всех чисел (я на яваскрипте написал просто для того, чтобы вы поняли идею как обойти загаданный ноль).

Comment: Подскажите как дописать код к программе? По заданию в верху?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аккуратнее с чтением по nextDouble() !

Что будет, если ввести не число, а букву, точку, знак ???

Ошибки ввода надо правильно обрабатывать, а волнующий Вас счетчик попыток перед циклом установите в ноль и после System.out.print("Вводите ваше число: "); инкрементируйте его, а вместе с "До свиданья!" распечатайте.

Answer (score 1):

Не шарю в яве, предположу:

```
//prog = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 10) + 10); // " * (10 - 10)" - это круто))
do { 
  prog = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) - 10;
  } while (prog == 0);
```

Comment: По идее как раз то, что ему надо.

Comment: Подскажите как дальше до писать программу 
Программа должна считать количество попыток, которое потребовалось пользователю, чтобы угадать число. И в конце сообщать, сколько было попыток, также должна подсказывать пользователю, что он ошибся в знаке, если программа загадала положительное число, а пользователь ввёл отрицательное. И наоборот.

Comment: @turtles, я настолько точно не шарю) А вообще если б вы ответы принимали - вам бы чаще отвечали)